# Start new Activity with Google+ sign in button

Tags: android, google-plus

How do you start a new activity with the Google plus sign in button?

I have this in my `activity_main.xml` file:

```
 <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
     android:id="@+id/btn_sign_in"
       android:onClick="launchGooglePlusSignIn"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     >

 </com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton>

 <Button
     android:id="@+id/button1"
     android:onClick="launchGooglePlusSignIn"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:layout_above="@+id/btn_sign_in"
     android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
     android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
     android:text="Button" />
```

and in my MainActivity, I have this:

```
 public void launchGooglePlusSignIn(View view) { //Must have a view as the ONLY parameter.This will be the view that was clicked
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, GooglePlusHandlerActivity.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}
```

When I run the app and click the Google button, nothing happens but when I click the other button, (as expected) am taken to the new activity.I really need to handle the Google plus signin, signout, access revocation etc in another activity, how can i start the activity with the google button?

Comment: set OnclickListener in GooglePlusActivity and implement implements OnClickListener, ConnectionCallbacks, OnConnectionFailedListener in GooglePlusActivity

Comment: I don't really understand you...but like I said, am trying to start the GooglePlusHandlerActivity from the MainActivity.Why would I implement the onClickListener there? Could you explain further?

Answer (score 0):

Follow [this](http://www.androidhive.info/2014/02/android-login-with-google-plus-account-1/) tutorial for google plus login.Here you will find a method called

**public void onConnected(Bundle arg0){}**.
Write your intent code within that method.It will work.

Comment: To get to the onConnected(Bundle arg0) method, wouldn't I need to be logged into GPlus already?

Comment: yes...first you will authenticate and after that if your authentication is successful then you will be redirected to the page you want

Comment: Yeah.But that isn't what I want to do.I need to start the other activity AFTER clicking the GPlus button, and then start the login process from the onCreate() method of the new Activity.I have used the tutorial in the link you provided to login to GPlus already, but the code is bulky to include in my MainActivity, that's why i need to do it somewhere else.

Comment: Oh...then you cannot use the google button...you have to use another button...whenever you click the google button the reference of GoogleApiClient will try to connect via .connect(),failing of which it will do nothing as in your case.

Answer (score 0):

With help from [this tutorial](https://anujarosha.wordpress.com/2011/11/13/how-to-implements-onclicklistener-for-a-view-item-in-android/) I was able to solve this problem.

I needed to initialize the buttons and then set `onClickListener`s in my MainActivity. My MainActivity now looks like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

private SignInButton signInButton;
private Button otherButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    signInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
      signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    otherButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button1);
      otherButton.setOnClickListener(this);

}


@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch(v.getId()) {

    case R.id.button1:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent ordinaryButtonClickedIntent = new Intent(this, GooglePlusHandlerActivity.class);
        startActivity(ordinaryButtonClickedIntent);
        break;
    case R.id.btn_sign_in:
        //Toast.makeText(this, "Button CLicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent GPlusButtonClickedIntent = new Intent(this, GooglePlusHandlerActivity.class);
        startActivity(GPlusButtonClickedIntent);
        break;

    }
}
```

I don't need these line in the buttons in my activity_main.xml file anymore:

```
android:onClick="launchGooglePlusSignIn"
```