# SignInButton in Fragment - and onClick is never called in MainActivity

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services, google-plus-signin

I have successfully followed the guide [Accessing Google APIs](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).

After that I have decided to move some of the code into fragment:

[image: screenshot]

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
        android:id="@+id/login_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="googleLogin" />

</FrameLayout>
```

And in the MainActivity I have moved GoogleApiClient object creation from `onCreate()` to `googleLogin()` method:

```
public void googleLogin(View v) {
    mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();

    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
}
```

However the method is never called (as I see in debugger).

What is wrong here, is it a bug (ignoring `onClick` XML attribute) in the current [SignInButton](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/common/SignInButton) implementation?

Comment: Try moving your `googleLogin()` method into the Fragment Class. Since the Click event belongs to `SignInButton`, which resides in that layout.

Comment: I've tried, but it hasn't helped (probably because the `onClick` methods are usually called not in Fragment, but in parent Activity).

Comment: You could try: add `implements OnClickListener` to your Fragment AND rename your method so `@Override
 public final void onClick(final View v)` (after moving it in the Fragment)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before the button click

```
         mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                    .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                    .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                    .addApi(Plus.API)
                    .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                    .build();
         btnSignIn = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
         btnSignIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v)
                    {
                        if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
                            mSignInClicked = true;
                            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                        }
                    }
                });


     @Override
        public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
           if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN)
                {
                    if (resultCode != RESULT_OK)
                    {
                        mSignInClicked = false;
                    }

                    mIntentInProgress = false;

                    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                        mGoogleApiClient.reconnect();
                    }
                }


        }



@Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle bundle)
    {
        mSignInClicked = false;
        if (Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient) != null)
        {

            Person currentPerson = Plus.PeopleApi.getCurrentPerson(mGoogleApiClient);
            //Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,str_id,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            str_first_name = currentPerson.getDisplayName();
            google_id = currentPerson.getImage().getUrl();
            System.out.println("google_id==  "+google_id);
            str_email = Plus.AccountApi.getAccountName(mGoogleApiClient);
            str_mobile ="";
            int temp=currentPerson.getGender();
            if(temp==0)
            {
                str_gender="male";
            }
            else if(temp==1)
            {
                str_gender="female";
            }

            str_date_of_birth=currentPerson.getBirthday();
           // Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,str_gender,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           // Toast.makeText(Login_Activity.this,str_date_of_birth,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



        }

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult connectionResult) {

        if (!mIntentInProgress) {
            if (mSignInClicked && connectionResult.hasResolution()) {
                // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
                // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
                try {
                    connectionResult.startResolutionForResult(this, RC_SIGN_IN);
                    mIntentInProgress = true;

                } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                    // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
                    // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
                    mIntentInProgress = false;
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

[Google+ Platform for Android](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started)

Answer (score 3):

Had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27544442/start-new-activity-with-google-sign-in-button) same issue once.It won't work from the XML file.Use it in your Fragment or Activity.Remember to initialize your button before you use it:

```
signInButton = (SignInButton)findViewById(R.id.btn_sign_in);
  signInButton.setOnClickListener(this);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not try removing the onClick in the xml and put it in the fragment that you're creating the layout.

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout, container, false);
    login_button = ( com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton ) view.findViewById(R.id.login_button);
    login_button.setOnClickListener( this );
    return view;
}

@Override
public void onClick( View v )
{
    switch ( v.getId() )
    {
        case R.id.login_button:
            mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
            .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
            .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
            .addApi(Plus.API)
            .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
            .build();
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, the "code way" suggested by Naveen and you works (+1), but I was just curious, why "XML way" was not working for `SignInButton`... what has Google missed to implement there?

Comment: I'm not familiar with the google implementation on this but I gather it's just due to Fragments not being able to receive onClicks via xml as it is an inflated view and not set as content view via onCreate in the Activity.